# How to place a CSS3 cube on top of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a project that places CSS3 cubes on top of another CSS3 cube (onclick) using the HTML DOM (yeah I know canvas is better),

This code is what I have now:

```
<html>
<section>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_stylesheet_files/index_stylesheet_file_01.css">
        <script rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="index_javascript_files/index_javascript_file_01.js"></script>
    </head>
</section>

<section>
    <head>

        <!-- this is the center cube, where all cubes are 'build' around -->

        <div class="cube">
            <div class="inner_center_cube">
                <!-- front side -->
                <div class="side_01_center_cube" onclick="place_cube_side_01_10_00_00()" style="background-color: red; transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(50px)      " ></div>
                <!-- back side -->
                <div class="side_02_center_cube" onclick="place_cube_side_02_01_00_00()" style="background-color: blue; transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(50px)   " ></div>
                <!-- left side -->
                <div class="side_03_center_cube" onclick="place_cube_side_03_00_10_00()" style="background-color: green; transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px)   " ></div>
                <!-- right side -->
                <div class="side_04_center_cube" onclick="place_cube_side_04_00_01_00()" style="background-color: yellow; transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px) " ></div>
                <!-- top side -->
                <div class="side_05_center_cube" onclick="place_cube_side_01_00_00_10()" style="background-color: orange; transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px)  " ></div>
                <!-- bottom side -->
                <div class="side_06_center_cube" onclick="place_cube_side_06_00_00_01()" style="background-color: brown; transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px)  " ></div>
            </div>
        </head>
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <head>
        <script rel="javascript" type="text/javascript">

            function place_cube_side_01_10_00_00() // function for placing the cube on 'top' of the other cube,
                                                   // there are also functions for other sides as well
            {
                $('<div style="perspective: 800px; perspective-origin: 50% 100px"'                                                                                                                                           +
                  '<div class="inner_top_cube" style="width: 100px; transform-style: preserve-3d; transform: rotateX(-45deg) translateZ(100px);">'                                                                                                                                 +
                  // front side //
                  '<div class="side_01_top_cube" onclick="place_cube_side_01_10_00_00()" style="background-color: red; transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(50px); position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; "></div>' +
                  // back side //
                  '<div class="side_02_top_cube" onclick="place_cube_side_02_01_00_00()" style="background-color: blue; transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(50px); position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; "></div>' +
                  // left side //
                  '<div class="side_03_top_cube" onclick="place_cube_side_03_00_10_00()" style="background-color: green; transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px); position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; "></div>' +
                  // right side //
                  '<div class="side_04_top_cube" onclick="place_cube_side_04_00_01_00()" style="background-color: yellow; transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px); position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; "></div>' +
                  // top side //
                  '<div class="side_05_top_cube" onclick="place_cube_side_01_10_00_00()" style="background-color: orange; transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);  "></div>' +
                  // bottom side //
                  '<div class="side_06_top_cube" onclick="place_cube_side_06_00_00_01()" style="background-color: brown; transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);  "></div>' +
                  '</div>'                                                                                                                                                       +
                  '</div>'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                 ).insertAfter('.cube');

            }

        </script>
    </head>
</section>
```

The only problem is the second cube on top is rotated 45 degrees towards the user, and some to the right:

[image: example]

It needs to perfectly fit on top of the bottom cube. How to do that?

Comment: I don't see any code that shows you've put in the work to come up at least with a minimum amount of maths to compute "where the cube should go", so: if you haven't read [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) you should probably do that, and note that it's pretty clear that you are first expected to do a bit of research yourself. No code, and no mention how you thought about doing it, strongly suggests you haven't done that require part yet. Aligning 3D shapes is not a trivial task, and a tutorial on it rather than an SO answer will be far more valuable for you.

Comment: any recommendations for good tutorials then?, or do in need to make another whole question for it? (for the tutos) it was not the meaning to ask for a SO answer, this whole thing freaks me out for the pas couple of days, and yeah ive seen too many tutorials on it so far

Comment: As per [what is on-topic on Stackoverflow](/help/on-topic), you can't post questions asking for tool/tutorial/library/etc recommendations. Your question will get closed as off-topic. What you want to do has nothing to do with CSS3, and everything to do with 3D maths, so you want to be finding tutorials for those. Specifically, you want to learn how to use rotation and translation matrices, which let you position your cubes with respect to the origin. This is complex enough that people have written 3D js libraries to deal with this: this is *not* a quick and easy thing to learn.

Comment: thank you @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, you are right about that, then there is 1 thing to do for me: follow some tutorials and learn the basics of rotation and translation matrices first